# How do I round up to the highest multiple of 10 in python?

Tags: python, rounding

I sort of know how to use a roundup function and this is what I currently have (this is the whole program):

```
#Step 1
print("Enter the first digit of your GTIN code")
digit_1 = int(input())

print("Enter the second digit")
digit_2 = int(input())

print("Enter the third digit")
digit_3 = int(input())

print("Enter the fourth digit")
digit_4 = int(input())

print("Enter the fifth digit")
digit_5 = int(input())

print("Enter the sixth digit")
digit_6 = int(input())

print("Enter the seventh digit")
digit_7 = int(input())

#Step 2
total_1 = digit_1 * 3
total_2 = digit_2 * 1
total_3 = digit_3 * 3
total_4 = digit_4 * 1
total_5 = digit_5 * 3
total_6 = digit_6 * 1
total_7 = digit_7 * 3

#Step 3
final_total = total_1 + total_2 + total_3 + total_4 + total_5 + total_6 + total_7


#Step 4
import math
def roundup(final_total):
    return int(math.ceil(final_total / 10.0)) * 10
final_total_2 = roundup(final_total)


GTIN_number = final_total - final_total_2

print("Your GTIN number is", GTIN_number)
```

Basically this is the end of my program of how to calculate a GTIN number.The program doesn't calculate the correct GTIN number. For example the number 3613296 should give the last digit (8th digit) as 6, however, it answers as -6.
I hope you can understand what I mean. Please could anybody break it down and explain it as I am a beginner.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you need to put this line: `final_total_2 = roundup(final_total)`

Comment: @Lebby, add some examples as your question is being misunderstood

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to incorporate the second variable; however, do you know how to round the final_total to the highest multiple of 10?

Comment: I've edited the question and incorporated the whole program @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @Lebby, are you actually looking for the moulo?

Comment: What's a 'moulo'? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: `3613296 % 10 -> 6` meant modulo

Comment: Alright, no need to dumb it down that much. As I clearly stated before, it was a silly mistake. @JoranBeasley

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After including the

```
final_total_2 = roundup(final_total)
```

your program should work fine. What's happening when you try to run it?

EDIT:
Based on comments, what OP wants is

```
GTIN_number = 9-(final_answer-1)%10
```

or

```
GTIN_number = final_answer_2 - final_answer
```

if final_answer_2 is a rounded up final_answer.

Comment: The program does work however, the GTIN number isn't correct once I have checked it with an example.

Comment: Are you sure the GTIN_number = final_total - final_total_2 line is correct? If final_total_2 is just final_total rounded up to the nearest 10, then that would be equal to GTIN_number = final_total % 10 - 10. Is that what you want? For example, if final_total=125, GTIN_number would become -5.

Comment: Alternatively, could you post the example you are trying that isn't working?

Comment: % is modulo, which means take the remainder if you divide by the number. For example, 15%10 is 5, because the remainder of 15/10 is 5.

Comment: The example is as follows: 3613296 is the 7 digit GTIN code. The 8 Digit GTIN code answer should be 6, however in the program, the answer appears as -6. @Sepehr Nazari

Comment: That's simply GTIN_number = final_total_2 - final_total. You were subtracting the wrong way.

Comment: I edited my answer for a simpler way to write what you're trying to do. However, if your teacher says you must use a roundup function, then simply reversing the order of subtraction should do it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my stupid mistake, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
roundup=round(GTINT, -1)
GTIN8 = int(roundup - GTINT) % 10
```

Give this a whirl, Sonny Jim.